# Thymeleaf can't bind zoneddatetime to input field

Tags: java, thymeleaf

Here is my form

```
<form th:action="@{/pages/org/create}" th:object="${org}" method="post" id="createOrgForm">
                    <div class="row">
                       <div class="form-group col-sm-12">
                          <label for="name">Name</label> <input class="form-control" id="name" type="text" th:field="*{name}" />
                       </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="row">
                       <div class="form-group col-sm-12">
                          <label for="uuid">Uuid</label> <input class="form-control" id="uuid" type="text" th:field="*{uuid}" />
                       </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="row">
                       <div class="form-group col-sm-12">
                          <label for="expiryDate">Expiry Date</label> 
                          <input class="form-control" id="expiryDate" type="date" name="expiryDate" th:value="${#temporals.format(org.expiryDate, 'dd/MMM/yyyy HH:mm', 'en')}"/>/>
                       </div>
                    </div>
                 </form>
```

The object has name and uuid which are strings
It also has an expiryDate which is a zonedDateTime

I want to return expiryDate as a zoneddatetime but I can't find any examples of this

Any one Know how to do this?

If anymore details are needed let me know

I have this error

There was an unexpected error (type=Bad Request, status=400).
Validation failed for object='org'. Error count: 1

because org.expiryDate is a string and its expecting a zoneddatetime

```
public class OrganizationDto extends TemporallyScopedEntityFlatDto {

private static final long serialVersionUID = -2191341305487098272L;

public static OrganizationDto fromEntity(final Organization o) {
    if (o == null) {
        return null;
    }
    final OrganizationDto dto = new OrganizationDto();
    DtoUtil.copyVersioned(o, dto);
    DtoUtil.copyTemporallyScoped(o, dto);
    dto.setName(o.getName());
    dto.setUuid(o.getUuid());
    return dto;
}

@ApiModelProperty(value = "The display name of this organization.")
private String name;
@ApiModelProperty(value = "The unique identifier of this organization.")
private String uuid;

private ZonedDateTime expiryDate;

public String getName() {
    return name;
}

public String getUuid() {
    return uuid;
}

public void setName(final String name) {
    this.name = name;
}

public void setUuid(final String uuid) {
    this.uuid = uuid;
}
```

}

Comment: What do you mean "can't"? Do you get an error? Incorrect behavior without one? What dependencies do you have in your project?

Comment: How is your POJO looks like.

Comment: Did you make the necessary adjustments for java.Time package Please check this https://www.baeldung.com/dates-in-thymeleaf Especially Chapter 3